# PocketSphinx install produces "cannot find file specified" when swigging

Tags: python, swig, pocketsphinx

I have been attempting to install the python PocketSphinx module for voice recognition on a Windows computer. In order to install the module I have downloaded swig (in an executable format) and put it in a directory, as well as modifying the PATH environment variable in order to include that directory. When testing swig in the command line, it seems to work as expected.

I then attempted to install PocketSphinx from the command line with the following command:

```
python -m pip install pocketsphinx
```

I received the following output:

```
Collecting pocketsphinx
  Using cached pocketsphinx-0.0.9.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pocketsphinx ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-otuma2ab\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8ombwfsqpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\sphinxbase
  copying sphinxbase\swig\python\sphinxbase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\sphinxbase
  copying sphinxbase\swig\python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\sphinxbase
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pocketsphinx
  copying pocketsphinx\swig\python\pocketsphinx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pocketsphinx
  copying pocketsphinx\swig\python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pocketsphinx
  running build_ext
  building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
  swigging sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
  C:\Users\John\Documents\swig\swigwin-3.0.8\swigwin-3.0.8\swig.exe -python -modern -Isphinxbase/include -Isphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Isphinxbase/include/win32 -outdir sphinxbase/swig/python -o sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
  Running setup.py clean for pocketsphinx
Failed to build pocketsphinx
Installing collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Running setup.py install for pocketsphinx ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-otuma2ab\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-nzaehrnb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\sphinxbase
    copying sphinxbase\swig\python\sphinxbase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\sphinxbase
    copying sphinxbase\swig\python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\sphinxbase
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pocketsphinx
    copying pocketsphinx\swig\python\pocketsphinx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pocketsphinx
    copying pocketsphinx\swig\python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pocketsphinx
    running build_ext
    building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
    swigging sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
    C:\Users\John\Documents\swig\swigwin-3.0.8\swigwin-3.0.8\swig.exe -python -modern -Isphinxbase/include -Isphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Isphinxbase/include/win32 -outdir sphinxbase/swig/python -o sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-otuma2ab\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-nzaehrnb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-otuma2ab\pocketsphinx\
```

I have attempted to extract the tar.gz file and run the setup.py myself instead (after extracting it):

```
python setup.py install
```

with the same result. After doing this, I have attempted to execute in the command line the command listed just above the error message (beginning with directory to swig.exe). As there was no output, I assume it was successful. This particular error message seems to only appear when I run the setup.py file. I cannot figure out the reason why the setup is failing.

Can someone advise me on how to fix this issue?

If it seems impossible to find the source of this error, I would appreciate an alternative way of installing the PocketSphinx module, which is my ultimate goal.

Comment: You can download prebuilt version here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pocketsphinx

Comment: And for swig error, you need to simply check if swig binary is actually under specified path, maybe there is a typo in path.